# How can I get the difference between the individual maximum values of different days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in MySQL, I am trying to find:

> The difference between a given day's maximum value occurred and the previous day's maximum value.

I was able to get  the maximum values for dates via:

```
select max(`bundle_count`), `Production_date` 
from `table` 
group by `Production_date`
```

But I don't know how to use SQL to calculate the differences between maximums for two given dates.

[image: Please find the input available]

am expecting output like this [image: Expecting Output]

Please help me.

Comment: your need self inner Join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update 1:  Here is a fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/818ad/2, that I used for testing.
Update 2:  Here is a fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f78d/10 that I used for further refining/fixing, based on Sandy's comments.
Update 3:  For some reason the case where there is no previous day was not being dealt with correctly.  I thought it was.  However, I've updated to make sure that works (a bit cumbersome--but it appears to be right.  Last fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f78d/45

---

I think @Grijesh conceptually got you the main thing you needed via the self-join of the input data (so make sure you vote up his answer!).  I've cleaned up his query a bit on syntax (building off of his query!):

```
SELECT
DATE(t1.`Production_date`) as theDate,
MAX( t1.`bundle_count` ) AS  'max(bundle_count)',
MAX( t1.`bundle_count` ) - 
    IF(
       EXISTS
           (
            SELECT date(t2.production_date)
            FROM input_example t2
            WHERE t2.machine_no = 1 AND 
                  date_sub(date(t1.production_date), interval 1 day) = date(t2.production_date)
        ),
        (
            SELECT MAX(t3.bundle_count)
            FROM input_example t3
            WHERE t3.machine_no = 1 AND 
                  date_sub(date(t1.production_date), interval 1 day) = date(t3.production_date)
            GROUP BY DATE(t3.production_date)
        ),          0
    )
    AS Total_Bundles_Used
FROM  `input_example` t1
WHERE t1.machine_no = 1
GROUP BY DATE( t1.`production_date` )
```

---

Note 1: I think @Grijesh and I were cleaning up the query syntax issues at the same time.  It's encouraging that we ended up with very similar versions after we were both doing cleanup.  My version differs in using `IFNULL()` for when there is no preceding data.  I also ended up with a `DATE_SUB`, and I made sure to reduce various dates to mere dates without time component, via `DATE()`

Note 2: I originally had not fully understood your source tables, so I thought I needed to implement a running count in the query.  But upon better inspection, it's clear that your source data already has a running count, so I took that stuff back out.

Comment: ..Thanks to appreciate  my efforts, this first time one appreciate me for inexact answer. And this is the way to help other.

Comment: @DWright :Am facing one problem , In output first day data not coming, can you please visit this link  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f78d/2   . I have created a table with one extra column    Thanks in advance

Comment: Excellent clarification.  I've updated my answer.  Also see Update 2 in the answer for fiddle.

Comment: @DWright I tried the code you provided, but still getting same output with missing first day data. as the problem is for first date it should print data as it is without checking condition,then from next date it should check condition with previous date. I'm trying to change code accordingly..can you please help

Comment: Sandy, I've change how I get at the previous day.  Hope this does it for you.  Good luck! See updated answer with updated fiddle above.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but you need something like this, Hope it will be helpful to you upto some extend:

Try this:

```
SELECT  t1.`Production_date` , 
         MAX(t1.`bundle_count`) - MAX(t2.`bundle_count`) ,  
         COUNT(t1.`bundle_count`)  
FROM `table_name` AS t1
    INNER  JOIN `table_name`  AS t2
   ON ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.`Production_date` , t2.`Production_date`)) = 1
GROUP BY t1.`Production_date`
```

**EDIT**

I create a table name = 'table_name', as below,

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
+---------------------+--------------+
| Production_date     | bundle_count |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2004-12-01 20:37:22 |            1 |
| 2004-12-01 20:37:22 |            2 |
| 2004-12-01 20:37:22 |            3 |
| 2004-12-02 20:37:22 |            2 |
| 2004-12-02 20:37:22 |            5 |
| 2004-12-02 20:37:22 |            7 |
| 2004-12-03 20:37:22 |            6 |
| 2004-12-03 20:37:22 |            7 |
| 2004-12-03 20:37:22 |            2 |
| 2004-12-04 20:37:22 |            1 |
| 2004-12-04 20:37:22 |            9 |
+---------------------+--------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My query: to find difference in  `bundle_count` between two consecutive dates:

```
 SELECT  t1.`Production_date` ,   
           MAX(t2.`bundle_count`) - MAX(t1.`bundle_count`) ,
           COUNT(t1.`bundle_count`)  
   FROM `table_name` AS t1     
     INNER  JOIN `table_name`  AS t2   
     ON ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.`Production_date` , t2.`Production_date`)) = 1
  GROUP BY t1.Production_date;
```

its output:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Production_date     | MAX(t2.`bundle_count`) - MAX(t1.`bundle_count`) | COUNT(t1.`bundle_count`) |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2004-12-01 20:37:22 |                                               4 |                        9 |
| 2004-12-02 20:37:22 |                                               0 |                       18 |
| 2004-12-03 20:37:22 |                                               2 |                       15 |
| 2004-12-04 20:37:22 |                                              -2 |                        6 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Grijesh :I'm getting error as right syntax to use near 'LeftJoin table_name t2 on datediff(t1.Production_date- t2.Production_date)==1

Comment: @sandy changed bit more , and now its not producing any compilation error on my system.

Answer (score 1):

This is PostgreSQL syntax (sorry; it's what I'm familiar with) but should fundamentally work in either database. Note this doesn't exactly run in PostgreSQL either because `group` is not a valid table name (it's a reserved keyword). The approach is a self-join as others have mentioned but I've used a view to handle the max-by-day and the difference as separate steps.

```
create view max_by_day as
select
  date_trunc('day', production_date) as production_date,
  max(bundle_count) as bundle_count
from
  group
group by
  date_trunc('day', production_date);

select
  today.production_date as production_date,
  today.bundle_count,
  today.bundle_count - coalesce(yesterday.bundle_count, 0)
from
  max_by_day as today
  left join max_by_day yesterday on (yesterday.production_date = today.production_date - '1 day'::interval)
order by
  production_date;
```

PostgreSQL also has a construct called [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) which is useful for this and a bit easier to understand. Just had to stick in a bit of advocacy for a superior database. :-P

```
select
  date_trunc('day', production_date),
  max(bundle_count),
  max(bundle_count) - lag(max(bundle_count), 1, 0)
over
  (order by date_trunc('day', production_date))
from
  group
group by
  date_trunc('day', production_date);
```

These two approaches differ in how they handle missing days in the data - the first will treat it as a 0, the second will use the previous day which is present. There wasn't a case like this in your sample so I don't know if this is something you care about.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the question, this answer isn't right. Leaving it anyway as someone may find the window functions interesting.

Comment: Fixed - now correctly diffs the current day and previous, where before I had it a cumulative sum of all previous days' max.