# Make calculation between rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following table from which I want to populate another table
with the subtraction of the budget of each year from the previous in each department.

E.g.  2013-2014 finance budget 500:

```
Year    Department  Budget

2013    Finance      3000
2014    Finance      3500
2015    Finance      4000
2013    Marketing    4500
2014    Marketing    5000
2015    Marketing    5500
2013    Sales        3000
2014    Sales        3500
2015    Sales        4000
```

I got no clue how to do it.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14252289/1673391

Answer (score 2):

In most modern SQL database systems, you could use a window function.  MySQL does not have window functions, but you can perform a self-join to put the needed values together on the same row:

```
select
  current.year AS year,
  current.department AS department,
  current.budget - previous.budget AS increase
from
  budget current
  JOIN budget previous
    ON current.department = previous.department
      AND current.year = previous.year + 1
```

Note that that will omit the earliest year for each department, as there is no previous year in those cases.  It would be possible to handle that differently, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LEAD and LAG

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(FY int, Dept varchar(20), Budget int);
GO

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(2013,'Finance',3000),
(2014,'Finance',3500),
(2015,'Finance',2000),
(2013,'Marketing',1500),
(2014,'Marketing',5500),
(2015,'Marketing',1500),
(2013,'Sales',3000),
(2014,'Sales',1500),
(2015,'Sales',3500);
GO

SELECT FY, Dept, Budget,
LAG(Budget) OVER(PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY FY)-Budget as PreviousYear,
LEAD(Budget) OVER(PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY FY)-Budget as NextYear
FROM #temp;
GO
```

Comment: i don't think you can use lag and lead in mysql.  Still I have to thank you for your help.